# Rails : How to truncate records when exporting to CSV with activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am working on my company site which has been created with rails and I'm a newbie.
There is a CSV exporter already included, and a validated_at column containing the date and the time. I want to truncate the export of this field to the date only. Here is the code :

```
def build_user(user:)
user = present(user)

id = user.id
first_name = user.first_name
last_name = user.last_name
email = user.email
registration_date = user.created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
marketing_communications_accepted = user.marketing_communications_accepted?
completed_profile = user.ready_for_approbation?
average_response_time = user.average_response_time
blocked = user.blocked?
confirmed_at = user.confirmed_at
approved_at = user.approved_at
blocked_at = user.blocked_at

[
  id, first_name, last_name, email, registration_date, marketing_communications_accepted,
  completed_profile, average_response_time, blocked, confirmed_at, approved_at, blocked_at
]
```

end
I have tried slice(9) and truncate(0, 9) without success. I can see those type of errors in logs :

```
> 2015-11-30T20:39:19.572933+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2015-11-30T20:39:19Z 3 TID-oul7oqy04 WARN: undefined method `slice' for Tue, 10 Nov 2015 15:01:33 EST -05:00:Time
2015-11-30T20:39:19.573019+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2015-11-30T20:39:19Z 3 TID-oul7oqy04 WARN: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.11/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb:364:in `method_missing'
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use the `to_date` method.

```
model.validated_at.to_date
```

or String format `strftime`

```
model.validated_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```